# Finding the CRC calculation method?

Tags: crc

So, I have a 433mhz RF signal for some remote control power outlets.
I have read the signals but just can't work out how they are doing the CRC.
The CRC is 9bits? at the end of the signal (as far as I can tell).
I can bute force CRCs which allows me to change the device ID and get the CRC.
Just not sure how it's actually being calculated.

The signal is made up of

```
[Device ID - 24 bits] [Button ID - 4 bits] [CRC - 9 bits]
```

Here are some valid signals

```
    1000 0001 0001 0110 0000 0000    1001    0011 1001 1  (button 1)
       Payload: 0x8116009  (135356425)         CRC: 0x73  (115)
    1000 0001 0001 0110 0000 0000    0101    0011 0001 1  (button 2)
       Payload: 0x8116005  (135356421)         CRC: 0x63  (99)

    1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111    1001    0010 1110 1  (button 1)
       Payload: 0xFFFFFF9  (268435449)         CRC: 0x5D  (93)
    1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111    0101    0010 0110 1  (button 2)
       Payload: 0xFFFFFF5  (268435445)         CRC: 0x4D  (77)

    0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    1001    0111 0110 1 (button 1)
        Payload: 0x9  (9)                      CRC: 0xED  (237)
    0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    0101    0111 1010 1 (button 2)
        Payload: 0x5  (5)                      CRC: 0xF5  (245)

    1011 1110 0010 0100 0000 0000    1001    0011 0100 1 (button 1)
        Payload: 0xBE24009  (199376905)        CRC: 0x69  (105)
    1011 1110 0010 0100 0000 0000    0101    0011 1000 1 (button 2)
        Payload: 0xBE24005  (199376901)        CRC: 0x71  (113)
```

I know all the button ID's. And it appears the device ID can be anything as long as the CRC is correct. I have a script that runs through all 256 possible CRCs so I can generate more values if required.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know it's a CRC or could it be some other form of checksum?

Comment: I was just assuming CRC. I have no idea sorry.
The difference between the CRC is 4 (sometimes +4, sometimes -4).
The difference between the Payloads is also 4. It could just be some simple XOR or something like that?

Comment: Yeah, XOR seems to play a part, , in the 3rd signal the last 4 bits are both $Button XOR b'1111'  so I wonder if it's inverting some part of the signal and XORing that against the button for that part.  The first part of the checksum seems unafected by the button, so maybe that's part of the message XOR another part of the message